# Como ordenar dois vetores (ordem crescente ) em um terceiro vetor usando apenas um laço?

Tags: c, array

Meu professor colocou esse problema e não estou conseguindo ordenar em ordem crescente apenas usando um laço para ordenar.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
    int i,a[5]={1,4,8,9,11},b[5]={3,6,7,10,15},c[10];

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){

        if(a[i]<b[i] || b[i]>a[i]){

        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d\n",c[i]);            
    }   
}
```

Comment: Procure sobre o algoritmo de Merge Sort

Comment: Já pensou em fazer um for dentro de outro for para testar condições?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro uni os dois vetores **a** e **b**, na variável **c**
conforme resposta aqui do stack no link
[União de dois vetores em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/311475/uni%C3%A3o-de-dois-vetores-em-c).

Após segui a lógica de programação utilizando apenas um vetor o c[10],
com os valores de **a** e **b** dentro.

Nos comentários tem o que cada variável faz.

Basicamente é comparar o vetor **c** com ele mesmo, utilizando dois contadores **i** e **j**, e armazenando os resultados na variável **aux**. Logo após colocando de forma ordenada fazendo a troca de variáveis e armazenando em
em **c[j]**.

Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
    int i,j;
    int a[5]={1,4,8,9,11};
    int b[5]={3,6,7,10,15};
    int c[10];
    int aux;

    /* Copia vetor 'a' para a primeira metade do vetor 'c' */
    memcpy( c, a, sizeof(a) );

    /* Copia vetor 'b' para a segunda metade do vetor 'c' */
    memcpy( c + 5, b, sizeof(b) );

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        if(c[i] < c[j]){
           //nesta parte que ocorre a troca e ordenação de varíaveis
           aux = c[i]; //recebe o menor valor, na varável temporária aux
           c[i] = c[j]; // repete com todos os valores no loop
           c[j] = aux; // recebe em ordem crescente no vetor c[j]

        }
      }
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d\n",c[i]); //imprime os resultados em ordem crescente
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i, j=0, k=0, a[5]={1,4,8,9,11}, b[5]={3,6,7,10,15}, c[10];
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if (a[j] < b[k]) {
            c[i] = a[j];
            j++;
        }
        else {
            c[i] = b[k];
            k++;
    }
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recomendo a leitura do seguinte link, só jogar o código pronto não ajuda muito, tente explicar o que vez de alteração para que quem perguntou possa aprender com sua resposta. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer