# União de dois vetores em C

Tags: c, array

Preciso realizar a união de dois vetores, resultando em um terceiro vetor:

```
a[5]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, b[5]={6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, c[10];
else if (select_menu == 4) {
    int select_f4, i, j, x;
    printf("Esta é uma opção que realiza a união dos conjuntos\n");
    printf("Resultado da união entre os dois vetores, com os números inseridos até o momento: \n");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        c[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (j=0; j<5; j++){
        c[i] = b[j];
    }
    for (x=0; x<10; x++){
        printf("%d, ", c[x]);
    }
}
```

O resultado deveria ser:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Ao invés disso, fica:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 257, 0, 1152, 0,

Comment: Como ao final do primeiro for a variável i sai com o valor 5 basta colocar c[i+j] = b[j]; no segundo for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta trocar `c[i] = b[j];` por `c[j + 5] = b[j];`.

Afinal de contas, os 5 primeiros itens são para `a` e os 5 últimos para `b`. Sem esse `+ 5`, você colocaria os de `b` por cima dos de `a`. No entanto, como você estava acessando o `c` com a variável `i` e o `b` com a `j`, estava colocando todos os elementos de `b` (vale o último, que é 10) em `c[5]`.

Esses números 257, 0, 1152 e 0 provavelmente são [**lixo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308094/132).

Uma forma de evitar erros como esse é declarar as variáveis apenas nos menores escopos necessários, que no seu caso é apenas no próprio `for`. Por exemplo:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            c[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            c[i] = b[j]; // O compilador vai mostrar que aqui há um erro!
            c[j + 5] = b[j]; // Isso seria o correto.
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            printf("%d, ", c[x]);
        }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Funcionou!

Answer (score 5):

Não é necessário nenhum laço `for` para resolver o seu problema!

Você pode usar a função `memcpy()` da biblioteca padrao `string.h` para unir os dois vetores em um terceiro vetor, veja só:

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int b[5] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int c[10];

/* Copia vetor 'a' para a primeira metade do vetor 'c' */
memcpy( c, a, sizeof(a) );

/* Copia vetor 'b' para a segunda metade do vetor 'c' */
memcpy( c + 5, b, sizeof(b) );
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/BUPAQA)

Alternativamente, você pode fazer essa união independente do tamanho dos vetores de entrada, contanto que o vetor de saída tenha a soma dos tamanhos dos vetores de entrada:

```
int a[7] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int b[3] = { 8, 9, 10 };
int c[10];

/* Copia vetor 'a' para a primeira porção do vetor 'c' */
memcpy( c, a, sizeof(a) );

/* Copia vetor 'b' para a segunda porção do vetor 'c' */
memcpy( c + (sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)), b, sizeof(b) );
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/RgtEpg)

Comment: Tem só um _caveat_ nessa alternativa em que não se informa o tamanho do vetor: "independente do tamanho" contanto que sejam vetores; não funciona se eu passar um ponteiro.

Answer (score 0):

Simples, no segundo `for` você não está somando a variável `i`, para ser mais claro ao seu modo de entendimento:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    c[i] = a[i];
}
for (j=0; j<5; j++){
    c[i] = b[j];
    i++;//desta forma você atualiza a posição em que será inserido no vetor c
}
for (x=0; x<10; x++){
    printf("%d, ", c[x]);
}
```

os valores que estavam sendo visualizados diferentes eram lixos das posições em do vetor `c`